# error while invoking api from api console in store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 api manager 2.6.0. I have created a prototyped api. When I try to invoke the api from store api console ,I get an error
TypeError: Failed to fetch

When I take the curl command from the api console and execute it from command prompt on the same server where wso2 api manager is installed I get the expected response.

As it a GET method , If I take the url and execute it on a chrome browser , it takes me the management console page. When I sign in to the management console page , the browser displays Error 405 - Method Not Allowed

When I trigger the endpoint from postman, it returns an html page which is the same management console page.

I have checked that the host and port for the gatewayendpoint and OAuthConfigurations/revokeapiurl are same  and the host is whitelisted in the store site.json.

Any idea what is wrong or how can I debug it.

[image: API Console]
[image: Command Line Invocation From Same Host]
[image: BrowserErrorAfterSigninginthecarbonconsole]
[image: Postman Invocation]

Comment: Your API Manager is in local or in a remote server ?

Comment: it is in aws ec2 instance

Answer (score 0):

Usually `TypeError: Failed to fetch` comes because of the self-signed certificate which comes by default with the server. If that is the case, accepting the security certificate from the browser should fix the problem.

From docs[2]:

> **Troubleshooting**
>
> If you cannot invoke the API's HTTPS endpoint (this causes the
> SSLPeerUnverified exception), it could be because the security
> certificate issued by the server is not trusted by your browser. To
> resolve this issue, access the HTTPS endpoint directly from your
> browser and accept the security certificate.
>
> If the API Manager has a certificate signed by a Certificate Authority
> (CA), the HTTPS endpoints should work out of the box.

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Invoke+an+API+using+the+Integrated+API+Console

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188294/discussion-on-answer-by-bee-error-while-invoking-api-from-api-console-in-store).